# android accurate battery level changes?

Tags: android, power-management

I have written an application, and I want to know how much of the battery it consumes.

I'm testing it on smartphone (ACER Liquid Mt), but I can only read the battery level with an accuracy of 1% via the battery manager.

It will take a lot of runs to make the percentage decrease with 1%. So my question is this: Is it possible to get a more accurate battery level and is the battery level trustable?

I read some things that the battery level in software wouldn't be very accurate.

Answer (score 1):

*It will take a lot of runs to make the percentage decrease with 1%* doesn't mean it is inaccurate, It could be that the battery is very durable.  And because it is in percentage, 1 percent of battery power could be a lot of energy.

For getting battery level, I use a BroadcastReceiver, you may try it and see if it is accurate enough:

```
class BatteryLifeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", 100);

            int batteryLevel = (float) level / scale;
            // use batteryLevel...
        }
    }
} 

// register the receiver in Activity.onResume()
registerReceiver(mBatteryLifeBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
// unregister it in Activity.onPause()
unregisterReceiver(mBatteryLifeBroadcastReceiver);
```